# Convert name of a generic element to URL in Django

Tags: python, django, urlencode

my goal is to get an URL of a product page starting from the name of the product.

For Example

from

```
"My Product 2.0"
```

i want to get

```
 www.example.com/my-product-2-0/
```

from **My Product 2.0** --> **my-product-2-0**

How?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a template or view code, or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)?

Comment: @Talvalin I'm in a view.

Comment: @Sindri not yet. Can you show me an Use Case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a slugify function for exactly this:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify("My Product 2.0")   # 'my-product-20'
```

Note in the current development version (soon to be 1.5) this has moved to `django.utils.text`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions:

```
import re
string="My Product 2.0"
rs=re.compile(r"\W+")
string=re.sub(rs, "-", string)
print string
```

You might have to play aroung a bit with the regular expression, depending on what exactly you want to have replaced with "-".